# Compiling for iOS 11.0, but module 'ESPProvision' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]compiling for iOS 11.0, but module 'ESPProvision' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: /Users/sumitsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/espidfrn1-ddsrubfjldnfvphfpnpvvfbalpmg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ESPProvision/ESPProvision.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you have a deployment target `11.0` when in fact it is supposed to be `13.0`.

So just go into XCode, select your project and change the `iOS deployment target`.

After that, just clean your build, run `pod install` and it should work.

**EDIT:**

Change minimum deployment target as well:
[image: Minimum deployment]

[image: XCode]

Comment: I tried but still facing same error

Comment: Can you try changing the minimum deployment target inside of target as well?

Comment: Its already higher then 11.0. Its 13.0